# NPOI C#: best way from Workbook to byte[]

Tags: c#, npoi, hssfworkbook

We have done an utility method to return a `byte[]` from an `IWorkBook` (NPOI).

```
public static byte[] WorkbookToByteArray(IWorkbook workbook, bool flush = false)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.Write(ms);
        if (flush) ms.Flush();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Now we have 2 questions:

1. Can we remove the Flush line for the `MemoryStream`? There is an using, so perhaps...
2. How can we free RAM at the end? At the moment, seems that the GC wait to clean the workbook from memory.

**EDIT:**
More information about RAM situation (the example here is with a very small Excel, about 259KB - to save time, normally we have huge generation of Excel - like 25-30MB or over).
[image: snapshot1]

[image: snapshot2]

Comment: `if (flush) ms.Flush();` <-- Remove this line and the `bool flush = false` parameter: they're both unnecessary (as `MemoryStream` isn't buffered and so doesn't need flushing, and callers of `WorkbookToByteArray` shouldn't be concerned with internal IO/flushing/buffering details).

Comment: _"How can we free RAM at the end? At the moment, seems that the GC wait to clean the workbook from memory."_ - how big is the output `byte[]`, exactly? And what is the original problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @Dai We have file Excel bigger than 20-30MB. But on our iis pool takes more than 2GB RAM. We need to free istantly the memory for the application.

Comment: 2GB RAM usage by `w3wp.exe` **is normal**: in server situations (like in IIS) then .NET will 
use _huge_ (like 250-500MB) memory pre-allocations as space for the GC heap, **per core**. For example, on my 16-core desktop machine, simply starting a minimal ASP.NET 4.8 project in VS and IIS Express will take 1-2GB out of my RAM _just like that_. It sounds like a lot, but I strongly doubt your IIS box is actually starved for RAM, and if it is then the best solution is to reconfigure IIS to limit memory usage, not try to microoptimize your ASP.NET code without _at least_ having run your profiler.

Comment: @Dai The problem is that 2GB is only for the NPOI Workbook, iis application pool normally is 1-2GB. So we have a pool with more than 4GB RAM. The server is very limited, and there are a lot of other application pool. So we can't do too much on the server itself. My question is specific for "free" memory after generate a huge Excel.

Comment: Have you used a memory profiler to see **exactly** where the memory is being used? If not, _why not_?

Comment: Obviously, otherwise why would I ask the question above?

Comment: So what did the profiler say? Do you have a screenshot of the profiler report? Objects in .NET are not monoliths, even if your `IWorkbook` instance is consuming gigabytes your profiler will still give you a per-heap-object breakdown and show any inadvertent strong-references that might be keeping large objects live longer than is necessary.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a heap size of **84MiB**, not 1.2GiB (`86,576.20 KiB` == 84 MiB). The 1.2GB memory usage at the top you're seeing is the _entire process_ commit charge (or working-set?) - it _does not_ indicate that 1.2GB of RAM is being gobbled up by .NET objects: that 1.2 GB is your reserved (per-core) GC heaps which are likely almsot entirely empty. In summary: **this all looks normal to me** and I don't feel like you need to chase this problem any further.